# How to save image assets on Firebase and use their public URLs in my app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I need to store images on Firebase and display them in my React application using Firebase.

This is not an image upload feature. I am talking about images that will be displayed in information static pages.

The closest resource I found was [Firebase's Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/), however, this aimed at apps that allow users to upload their own content.

I also found [Firebase's Hosting page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/), I followed some of the steps which include installing the firebase CLI. However, it doesn't make it clear how to save my image assets there. Maybe FTP?

The best alternative I found so far was to save my images in my app's public folder, however, from a performance standpoint it would be more interesting to have those images saved on Firebase directly and use their URLs in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simpler than I thought.

You can simply access your app page on Firebase, go in the "Develop" section and choose "Storage".

In the "Storage" page you can upload files and a default public URL will be generated for them. I chose the "Download URL" for each image that I uploaded.

Comment: Be aware that if you reach the free limits you will be charged each time a user will display the image, since it will be downloaded from the Cloud Storage (see https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for the heads-up! I believe we won't run into this issue, we are talking about less than 1MB of images in a page that is not very popular :)